# How to change redirect_to in devise with custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I use devise with custom controller (user controller). Rather than logging in and going to `user/edit`, I prefer to serve the home page. To do so, I need to edit the devise session create controller method.

I know I can edit the devise custom controller by following the instructions devise provides:

```
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
```

So following those instructions, how do I simply have the `create` method do exactly what it currently does, but `redirect_to "/"` rather than what it's currently doing?

Note [here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L19-L23)'s what it's currently doing:

```
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
clean_up_passwords(resource)
yield resource if block_given?
respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
```

Also note, I *could* copy that code directly from devise on github, then edit it, like so:

```
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
clean_up_passwords(resource)
yield resource if block_given?
redirect to: "/"
```

but I want to do this using the `super` method as that's what's recommended in the devise instructions.

Comment: Have you tried [after_sign_in_path_for](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers:after_sign_in_path_for) Devise helper?

Answer (score 2):

No need to redefine `create` action, as Devise allows you to do just that with `after_sign_in_path_for` method.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```